# Can you programmatically switch serverless cron functions on/off

Tags: cron, serverless-framework, serverless

Scenario:

- I want function A to run every minute, but not 24/7. More like 5-10 hours per week. However, a simple cron outlining these times will not do here because the 5-10 hours per week are dynamic and keep changing.
- Function B will run e.g. every 30 minutes and determine whether Function A should be running or not. If so, it will switch it 'on', if not, it will switch it 'off'

Is this doable using Serverless.com (or any of the FAAS providers it uses)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

## Solution #1: Use s3 to save switch state

- You can have the second function write to a file on S3 the state of the switch (`ON` or `OFF`).
- Schedule the first function to run every min. But make sure it checks the content of the "switch file" from S3 before it starts executing it's logic.

**Cost**

It won't cost you a lot because: `60` times an hour * `24` hours a day * `31` days a month = `44,640` calls / month. If it would take an extra `100ms` to read the flag and you've set the memory to `1GB` then this will translate to `44,640` * (`0.00001667` GB-SECOND / `10` -100ms per second-) = `$0.07441488` / month.

In addition to `44,640` S3 GET request (`0.001` per `1,000` requests) = `44,640` * (`0.001` / `1000`) = `$0.04464` / month.

## Solution #2: Control the cron of func1 from func2

In function 2, using the AWS CloudWatchEvents API you can create/update the rule's ScheduleExpression (e.g. `"cron(* * * * * *)"`) that that triggers function 1. Read more [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.put_rule)

Comment: Hmmm - I've ended up doing similar to what you suggest. I guess though, while that works as a workaround, the answer to the question would be 'no' for now?

Comment: If you can edit your answer to say that I can mark it as the accepted answer (if and until a 'yes' comes around...

Comment: @hemal the send solution does the switch on/off the Lambda functions tho